# Call Java varargs method from Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, variadic-functions

I'm using Spring class which has next ctor:

```
protected AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice(String... queryParamNames) {
        Assert.isTrue(!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(queryParamNames), "At least one query param name is required");
        this.jsonpQueryParamNames = queryParamNames;
}
```

I extend my class from class above(JSONPControllerAdvice.groovy):

```
public JSONPControllerAdvice(){

        super('callback')
}
```

But 'callback' comes as array to AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice `String[8]{'c', 'a'...}` but should come as `String[1]{"callback"}`.

I use Groovy v.2.3.6

What is wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `['callback'] as String[]` should work.  groovy somehow would be under the impression, that a cast is needed :/